# codeigniter 3.0 custom 404 not found error page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My problem is about custom error pages after upgrading to Codeigniter 3.0.

I used to have a `Errors` controller which handled 404 error page of the website - on this controller I have customized some parts of page, such as if user is logged in, it was showing username on the navigation bar and etc. *(yes, on 404 error page)*.

After upgrading to CI 3.0, I have noticed that error pages are handled in [different folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6JjY.png), I started to migrate to this way; but the problem is I can't load any variables to this page, such as *session variables* or can't even use any CI's functions on these pages.

I think this pages are supposed to be only HTML pages, but is there any way to load variables to these error pages?

Comment: Common checks make sure your controller class and file names have first letter upper case.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I have removed the controller class already and I am trying to use the new way - CI 3.0 way.

Comment: Unclear what you asking

Comment: @Abdulla Check this [screenshot](https://rjv.me/~rj/ci30.png). This is CI 3.0 directory structure, as you see error pages are handled differently than previous version. How can I load variables to these pages? such as session variables, or smth else?

Comment: you want custom error page??

Comment: @Abdulla I already have them. My problem is I can't load session variables on these pages. please read the question.

Comment: show your code as well

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set in `application/config/routes.php` the following route

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';
```

Then you need to create a new controller in your controllers directory `(application/controllers/)`

```
<?php 
class My404 extends CI_Controller 
{
 public function __construct() 
 {
    parent::__construct(); 
 } 

 public function index() 
 { 
    $this->output->set_status_header('404'); 
    $this->load->view('err404');//loading in custom error view
 } 
}
```

And create an `err404` view. Thats all!

Refer :[Reserved Routes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#reserved-routes)

Comment: Codeigniter 3 first letter should be upper case for class and filename

Comment: This does not work if you use the `show_404()` function.

Comment: @CodeGodie then you need to create a the file `application/core/MY_Exceptions.php` and override `show_404()` to show your custom error page

Answer (score 3):

It's not working in codeigniter 3, I overwrite the default view (`application/views/errors/html/error_404.php`) and added my custom view, now  `show_404()` is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

that is working good, but if redirect to an error, for example 404 with function show_404, your controller wont load your view, for a real 404 in the show_404 method, you have to go to the core of codeigniter and touch it.

\system\core\Common.php

this is an example of code:

```
function show_404(){
  $ci = get_instance();
  $ci->output->set_status_header(404);
  $ci->load->view('errors/error404_view');
  echo $ci->output->get_output();
  exit(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 3, instead of calling `show_404()`, I just redirected to the custom error controller function.

e.g. for the above scenario

```
if (404 condition...) {
    redirect("my404");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with the show_404 () function, you don't need to access the CI core and change how they are talking.
Just make the standard 404 view load your 404 view with `$CI->load->view(...)`

this will keep the original 404 code of the request and will not make an unnecessary redirect or core changes.

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->view('error-404');
```