# Codeigniter Custom 404 Page for different Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need assistance to get the correct method to display a custom 404 error page, for differect controllers. I have `home, welcome` as my controllers, but default controller is `welcome`. When the user Logs in, they are redirected to `home`. I need each of this conrtollers to have their own custom 404 error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set up a custom 404 controller in the application/config/routes.php file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479274/3585500https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479274/3585500)

`$route['404_override'] = 'my404controller';`

Create a `My404controller` and handle all the 404 errors in the `index()` using [`$this->uri->segment(0)`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?#CI_URI::segment).

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class My404controller extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index() {

  // $this->uri->segment(1) is *original* controller segment before routing.

  set_status_header(404); // set 404 header

  if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'home') {
     $this->load->view('home/home404');
     return;
  }

  if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'admin') {
     $this->load->view('admin/admin404');
     return;
  }

  if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'blog') {
     $this->load->view('blog/blog404');
     return;
  }

  // If there's no match to existing controller, default to generic 404 page view.
  $this->load->view('default404');

  }
}
```

Comment: It still not working, I am in the `home controller` but still the `404 error page` loads the default error page but not `if ($this->uri->segment(0) == 'home') {
            $this->load->view('errors/404doc');
            return;
        }` is not loaded

Comment: @Beroo Sorry! I retested and I think it's supposed to be useing `$this->uri-segment(1)` instead of segment(0).

Comment: Still it is directing the page to `$this->load->view('default404')` . Yet I am in `Home` controller......

Comment: @Beroo Maybe just var_dump $this->uri->segment(0) and segment(1) instead of loading the default404 view and see what the values are?

Comment: `var_dump($this->uri->segment(1));` outputs `home` while `var_dump($this->uri->segment(0));` outputs `NULL`