# I want to redirect to home page on every bad request by the user in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a website https://easyfreenotes.in/ it's working fine , but if i want to access any bad url which is not present actually , how can i redirect it to my home page without showing any bugs

```
Warning: include(/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/easyfree/public_html/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/easyfree/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268
```

Comment: please show your code. we can't figure it out by error.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't redirect it to the home page, you should show a 404 error for page not found and then you can put a button there that can redirect user to home page

[you can learn how to create (404) not found page here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-codeigniter-404-not-found-page/)

Comment: I made error.php file in controller and also My_ROUTES.PHP file in routes. Now i want to know     $this->router->show_404(); where i can call this

Comment: the answer of this question can help you


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478283/codeigniter-3-0-custom-404-not-found-error-page