# How to remove the 404 page not found server info in codeigniter 2.1.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have an issue with having a 404 error. The problem is it is showing the browser default 404 error without using my custom 404 error page.
it only occurs on this URL,

> `URL: domainname.com/index`

[This is how it. shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZDl.png)

Then,

1. I tried 301 redirections as

> `Redirect 301 /index https://www.domainname.com`

Sadly, it didn't work.

2. I have alredy done other .htaccess configs and here they are,

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine on
> Redirect /indexOR https://www.domainnameEnglish.com/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
> RewriteRule ^.* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
> </IfModule>
> ```

here indexOR is not a mistake, it's one of my route to redirect to the English version of the website
`$route['indexOR'] = 'site_index/indexOR';`

But still having the issue.

3. then I create a new route,

> `$route['index'] = 'site_index/index';`
> site_index -my controller,
> index - function which triggers the index page

But still having the issue.

My main target is to display my custom 404 page without showing this  [browser default 404 error with server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZDl.png)

briefly,
when the URL is domainname.com/anything (anything not included in the route file) it should be redirected to my custom 404 error page

THANKS!

Comment: _"it should redirected to my custom 404 error page"_ - your custom 404 error page, _specified where_, exactly ...? Are you talking about something set up _within_ your Codeigniter application? Because apparently these requests don't even make it that far.

Comment: `Redirect /indexOR https://www.domainnameEnglish.com/` - You have an erroneous `OR` in the rule you posted. You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper. "browser default 404" - That is the _server_ default, not "browser" default. You can remove the "server info" separately to changing the error document, although the goal would seem to trigger the CI error page? `'site_index/index';` - What's "site_index"?

Comment: okay. let's say, i wanna show up a custom 404 view instead of the server's default error when the URL is `domainname.com/index`, what should I do?

Comment: this should work for CI 2.x as well, please confirm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479274/2275490